# Atualizar todos os fields de um model, exceto a primary key

Tags: python, django, orm, django-rest-framework, data-warehouse

Estou iniciando os estudos no DRF e durante um teste me deparei com a seguinte situação: seria possível alterar os `fields` de uma classe com a exceção da `primary key`?

Minha primeira tentativa foi permitir que a pk fosse atualizada, para que os outros campos também fossem, entretanto não obtive sucesso.

Entendo que atualizar a pk não seja uma boa prática, mas ela também não permite que eu atualize os demais campos da classe. Acredito que o erro seja bobo, mas eu não sei como resolvê-lo.

Aqui está o que foi feito até agora:

*models.py*.

```
    class Pessoa(models.Model):
        cpf = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
        nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
        sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
        cidade = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
        estado = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
        history = HistoricalRecords()
```

*serializers.py*

```
class VehicleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ['cpf','nome','sobrenome','cidade','estado']


        def create(self, validated_data):
            indent, created = Pessoa.objects.update_or_create(
                cpf = validated_data.get('cpf', None),
                defaults={'ident': validated_data.get('ident', None)})
            return ident
```

Comment: Tens aqui documentação bastante completa, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

Comment: Quanto à tua questão atualizar a tua pk para os dados atualizar, isso não existe e nem o deves fazer. Atualizar restantes atributos, sim podes fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

Se que atualizar um campo definido como PK, é um forte indício que este campo não deveria ser uma PK. Parece-me que somente deseja que tal campo seja único.
Então sugiro algo assim:

```
 from uuid import uuid4
 class Pessoa(models.Model):
    id = models.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    history = HistoricalRecords()

class VehicleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Vehicle
    exclude = ['history','id']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if Vehicle.objects.filter(cpf=validated_data['cpf']).exists():
           raise serializers.ValidationError('CPF já cadastrado')

        return super(VehicleSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        validated_data.pop('cpf', None)
        return super(VehicleSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```